# How do I load a custom font from an embedded file into DirectWrite in a Metro app?

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, truetype, directx-11, directwrite

I have been fighting a losing battle against loading fonts from an embedded file for use with DirectWrite.  I am writing a simple puzzle game that has a C#/XAML interface but also uses SurfaceImageSource to add some DirectX content.

I have written a WinRT component that handles all of the DirectX code, and it works quite nicely.  Some of my DirectX content is text drawn using the DirectWrite API.  I can draw all the text I like so long as I'm loading an installed font from the system using **IDWriteFactory::GetSystemFontCollection()**, etc.  But, I cannot seem to find a way to load a custom font from an embedded file.

From what I can tell Metro apps are not allowed to load files from the filesystem in the same way as a traditional app.  So, the **IDWriteFactory::CreateFontFileReference()** method that takes a normal file path is worthless to me, right?  I need to load my file from an ms-appx URL.

So, I wrote a custom font loader in my WinRT component that implements the **IDWriteFontCollectionLoader** interface (which is a ton of work if you've never done it before btw) that loads the font from an ms-appx URL using the new **StorageFile** API.  Now, I can load my **IDWriteFontFile** and I can get a **IDWriteFontFace**, but if I try to call any of the truly useful methods on the font face it returns **E_UNEXPECTED**.  I can get the number of glyphs and the glyph indices, but if I try to call something like **GetGlyphRunOutline()** or **GetDesignGlyphMetrics()**, it fails with **E_UNEXPECTED**.  Using the same drawing code that generates an **ID2D1PathGeometry** using **GetGlyphRunOutline()** works great as long as I install the font file and get the **IDWriteFontFace** through the series of calls starting with **IDWriteFactory::GetSystemFontCollection()**.  I am working with a normal true type font.

So, how do I load a custom font from an embedded file into DirectWrite in a Metro app?  I'm probably just missing something easy, because I am certain that other people will want to be able to load custom fonts in this way.

I have a sample project (or could prepare one easily) for anyone who can help me identify my problem.

I have loaded the two **IDWriteFontFace** objects side by side, and I tried to figure out what is different between the one that works and the one that breaks.  What I need to see in order to find out why it is failing is opaque to me hidden behind inside the **IDWriteFontFace** interface.  HELP PLEASE!

Question also posted here: [Building Metro style games with DirectX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wingameswithdirectx/thread/3bc3f37d-4826-4df3-9748-2ea60ae23709)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the answer is... don't write a **IDWriteFontCollectionLoader**!  You can use **IDWriteFactory::CreateFontFileReference()** with the **StorageFile** API.  I was under the impression from all of the Microsoft Conference talks I had attended that in Metro you would be unable to access the native file system directly; the way forward would be to use the **StorageFile** API which references resources, etc. using ms-appx URLs.  I understood that this was done for concurrency and to allow the OS to insulate itself from Metro apps that would be downloaded from the store by creating a file system sandbox.  I think that is accurate.  But, I feel like I was led to believe that we would never be able to get native file system paths.  That is NOT true.  **IStorageFile** provides a way.  Just use **IStorageFile.Path**.  I never looked at it because I just assumed the **Path** property would hold the ms-appx URL that I used to create the object.  Microsoft probably provided this for exactly the purpose in my problem above: calling legacy COM interfaces that require a native path.

I haven't done any testing to determine whether the WinRT framework actually sandboxes you if you try to access a native file system path outside your own app package.  I'm betting that it does...